# How to tell a battery's ideal charging voltage with a circuit?

Tags: arduino, batteries, battery-charging, charger

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa5Qhl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've been looking to build a universal charger for my laptop and phone, and I'm wondering; is there a viable way to adjust the input voltage to match the battery's ideal charging voltage by measuring A and B across an arbitrary load?

The scenario is as follows;

0) I've got a universal charger that can output anywhere from 5V to 24V

1) I want to charge my phone, so I plug it into the universal charger

2) Without my interaction, the circuit and it's microcontroller adjusts itself to the required voltage (5V)

3) I now unplug my phone and plug my laptop in for charging

4) Without my interaction, the circuit and it's microcontroller adjusts itself to the required voltage (24V)

How can I measure the required voltage without checking the battery label?

Comment: you either have interaction or you don't ... you cannot have both .... you need to rethink what you are trying to do .....`measuring A and B across an arbitrary load` is interaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your scheme is that the battery isn't directly connected to the charging socket. There will be a **charging controller** in between:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAJidU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So from the charging port it is not possible to determine what voltage is needed to charge the device.

Only if there is **communication** between the power adapter and the Charging controller can your scheme work. Qualcomm Quickcharge is an example of that. If the charge controller does not support such a protocol then what you propose cannot be done.

Think about it: USB ports that are designed for 5 V can usually handle 6 V - 6.5 V at most, applying 24 V to such a port will for sure damage it severely.

Comment: I see - so basically I would have to figure out a way to interface with each proprietary charging controller in order to get it to tell me what voltage it needs.

Comment: *I would have to figure out a way to ...tell me what voltage it needs* Sure, **but** most charge controllers don't support this function so in practice you cannot get this interfacing to work. The charge controllers simply aren't designed for this.